# Google cloud compute VM instance not getting listed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud-compute

I lost my vm instance and a huge amount of data with it. I even paid the pending amount to google but when i went to the vm instance page, it is showing only create  instance menu. How can i recover my old vm instance. Please help

Comment: If the VM instance was deleted because of non-payment after the grace period expired, you will not be able to recover the instance or the data on the instance.

Answer (score 1):

As @John Hanley mentioned in comments " When a Google account is closed, GCP may impose an internal recovery period of up to 30 days, depending on past account activity. Once that grace period expires, it is marked for [deletion](https://cloud.google.com/security/deletion#stage_2_-_soft_deletion) ."